# How can I get sections with serial numbers in man man command on Mac terminal

Tags: osx, man

On MAC terminal, how can I get output something like this:

```
1 Executable programs or shell commands
2 System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
3 Library calls (functions within program libraries)
4 Special files (usually found in /dev)
5 File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
6 Games
7 Miscellaneous (including macro packages and conventions), e.g. man(7)
8 System administration commands (usually only for root)
9 Kernel routines [Non standard]
```

Comment: On older systems (through 10.5 at least), you would use [man manpages](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/manpages.5.html), but Apple appears to have removed this manual page from more recent OSX releases.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this?

```
man -a intro |                            # awk grabs the header from each intro man page
awk '/INTRO/ { $1 = substr($1,7,1)        # set $1 to x in INTRO(x)
               $2 = ""                    # set $2 to nothing
               sub(/INTRO\([0-9]\)/, "")  # remove the string INTRO(x) from last field
               print | "sort"
}'
```

The results:

```
1  General Commands Manual 
2  System Calls Manual 
3  Library Functions Manual 
5  File Formats Manual 
7  Miscellaneous Information Manual 
8  System Manager's Manual 
9  Kernel Developer's Manual
```

Note the missing sections.